# 2.8: How to add a button to the toolbar?

Tags: python, add-on

What is the proper way to add a button to the toolbar just to be visible in object-mode?

I try to port an old addon to Blender 2.8 and I managed to add a button to the toolbar, but the button is visible in all modes and not just in object-mode.
This is how I add the button:

```
def add_button(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    butt = layout.operator("object.match_transform", text="Bla")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MatchTransformsOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_tools_active.append(add_button)
```

Full code is here: [Addon on Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knekke/blender_addons/master/B28_match_transforms.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Campbell [added some stuff to the API](https://developer.blender.org/rBf29b80ff79ec7c6a2532d0b0eb5841d00cc7af1b) and had I been using the latest build I would have had access to a new code template:

```
# This example adds an object mode tool to the toolbar.
# This is just the circle-select and lasso tools tool.
import bpy
from bpy.utils.toolsystem import ToolDef
from bpy.types import WorkSpaceTool

class MyTool(WorkSpaceTool):
    bl_space_type='VIEW_3D'
    bl_context_mode='OBJECT'

    # The prefix of the idname should be your add-on name.
    bl_idname = "my_template.my_circle_select"
    bl_label = "My Circle Select"
    bl_description = (
        "This is a tooltip\n"
        "with multiple lines"
    )
    bl_icon = "ops.generic.select_circle"
    bl_widget = None
    bl_keymap = (
        ("view3d.select_circle", {"type": 'LEFTMOUSE', "value": 'PRESS'},
         {"properties": [("wait_for_input", False)]}),
        ("view3d.select_circle", {"type": 'LEFTMOUSE', "value": 'PRESS', "ctrl": True},
         {"properties": [("mode", 'SUB'), ("wait_for_input", False)]}),
    )

    def draw_settings(context, layout, tool):
        props = tool.operator_properties("view3d.select_circle")
        layout.prop(props, "mode")
        layout.prop(props, "radius")


class MyOtherTool(WorkSpaceTool):
    bl_space_type='VIEW_3D'
    bl_context_mode='OBJECT'

    bl_idname = "my_template.my_other_select"
    bl_label = "My Lasso Tool Select"
    bl_description = (
        "This is a tooltip\n"
        "with multiple lines"
    )
    bl_icon = "ops.generic.select_lasso"
    bl_widget = None
    bl_keymap = (
        ("view3d.select_lasso", {"type": 'LEFTMOUSE', "value": 'PRESS'}, None),
        ("view3d.select_lasso", {"type": 'LEFTMOUSE', "value": 'PRESS', "ctrl": True},
         {"properties": [("mode", 'SUB')]}),
    )

    def draw_settings(context, layout, tool):
        props = tool.operator_properties("view3d.select_lasso")
        layout.prop(props, "mode")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_tool(MyTool, after={"builtin.scale_cage"}, separator=True, group=True)
    bpy.utils.register_tool(MyOtherTool, after={MyTool.bl_idname})

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_tool(MyTool)
    bpy.utils.unregister_tool(MyOtherTool)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```